# How to initialize a posix semaphore from a static library during process startup?

Tags: static-libraries, semaphore

I have a static library that defines a semaphore. The semaphore needs to be initialized before any calls to the library (for the reason that it be can safely used by multiple threads from the same process).

Therefore, I would like to initialize (e.g. by running sem_init) the library's semaphore during the start-up of the process. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
// This seems to solve the problem. Init(void) will run before main()

void Init(void) __attribute__((constructor));
void Init(void) // This will always run before main()
{
    printf("HSA LIB Init\n");
    sem_init (&HSA_lib.semaphore, 0, 1);
}
```